# Dummy argument not agreeing with actual argument when passing function

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to implement Newton's method but I'm getting a confusing error message. In my code you'll see I called external with f1 and f2 which I assumes tells the computer to look for the function but it's treating them as variables based on the error message. I've read the stack overflow posts similar to my issue but none of the solutions seem to work. I've tried with and without the external but the issue still persists. Hoping someone could see what I'm missing.

````
implicit none 

contains 

subroutine solve(f1,f2,x0,n, EPSILON)
implicit none

real(kind = 2), external:: f1, f2
real (kind = 2), intent(in):: x0, EPSILON
real (kind = 2):: x
integer, intent(in):: n
integer:: iteration
x = x0

do while (abs(f1(x))>EPSILON)
  iteration = iteration + 1
  print*, iteration, x, f1(x)
  x = x - (f1(x)/f2(x))
  if (iteration >= n) then 
    print*, "No Convergence"
    stop
  end if  
end do

print*, iteration, x

end subroutine solve

end module newton   

Program Lab10
use newton
implicit none
integer, parameter :: n = 1000  ! maximum iteration
real(kind = 2), parameter :: EPSILON = 1.d-3
real(kind = 2):: x0, x
x0 = 3.0d0

call solve(f(x),fp(x),x0,n, EPSILON) 
  
contains

real (kind = 2) function f(x)  ! this is f(x)
implicit none
real (kind = 2), intent(in)::x
f = x**2.0d0-1.0d0
end function f

real (kind = 2) function fp(x)  ! This is f'(x)
implicit none
real (kind = 2), intent(in)::x
fp = 2.0d0*x
end function fp

end program Lab10```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be passing function results to your subroutine and not the functions themselves. Remove `(x)` when calling `solve()` and the problem will be resolved. But more importantly, this code is a prime example of how to not program in Fortran. The attribute `external` is deprecated and you better provide an explicit interface. In addition, what is the meaning of `kind = 2`. Gfortran does not even comprehend it. Even if it comprehends the kind, it is not portable. Here is a correct portable modern implementation of the code,

```
module newton

    use iso_fortran_env, only: RK => real64
    implicit none

    abstract interface
        pure function f_proc(x) result(result)
            import RK
            real(RK), intent(in)    :: x
            real(RK)                :: result
        end function f_proc
    end interface

contains

    subroutine solve(f1,f2,x0,n, EPSILON)

        procedure(f_proc)       :: f1, f2
        real(RK), intent(in)    :: x0, EPSILON
        integer, intent(in)     :: n
        real(RK)                :: x
        integer                 :: iteration
        x = x0

        do while (abs(f1(x))>EPSILON)
          iteration = iteration + 1
          print*, iteration, x, f1(x)
          x = x - (f1(x)/f2(x))
          if (iteration >= n) then
            print*, "No Convergence"
            stop
          end if
        end do

        print*, iteration, x

    end subroutine solve

end module newton

Program Lab10

    use newton

    integer, parameter  :: n = 1000  ! maximum iteration
    real(RK), parameter :: EPSILON = 1.e-3_RK
    real(RK)            :: x0, x
    x0 = 3._RK

    call solve(f,fp,x0,n, EPSILON)

contains

    pure function f(x) result(result) ! this is f(x)
        real (RK), intent(in)   :: x
        real (RK)               :: result
        result = x**2 - 1._RK
    end function f

    pure function fp(x) result(result) ! This is f'(x)
        real (RK), intent(in)   :: x
        real (RK)               :: result
        result = 2 * x
    end function fp

end program Lab10
```

If you expect to pass `nonpure` functions to the subroutine `solve()`, then remove the `pure` attribute. Note the use of `real64` to declare 64-bit (double precision) real kind. Also notice how I have used `_RK` suffix to assign 64-bit precision to real constants. Also, notice I changed the exponents from real to integer as it is multiplication is more efficient than exponentiation computationally. I hope this answer serves more than merely the solution to Lab10.

Comment: Much as `real(2)` is a non-portable, albeit common, type we can't say that `real(real64)` refers to anything in particular.  Even if it exists, it may not be "double precision" and it may not use 64 bits.

Comment: @francescalus That is true. If the compiler supports more than one kind with a particular size, the standard does not specify which one will be chosen for the constant. But using `iso_fortran_env` there is at least a systematic way of controlling the kind and the size corresponding to it.

Comment: @jack I agree, although I am inclined to keep `implicit none` in every possible program unit. Frequently, people tend to extract a specific function from a module to use elsewhere in some other codebase.

Comment: Hi, so I added your remedied solution of removing the (x) in solve but I got: "error 997 - An internal FUNCTION, such as F, cannot be used as an actual argument" and "error 997 - An internal FUNCTION, such as FP, cannot be used as an actual argument" as error messages. These are new error messages I haven't encountered in my work before so I'm unsure how to handle it.

Comment: @tyronebuckets This is a valid Fortran code as far as I can tell. What compiler are you using? It is likely that your compiler does not support Modern Fortran (2008). You can test it with Gfortran here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_fortran_online.php

Comment: @tyronebuckets Intel compiler also compiles and runs this code fine.

Comment: You're right, I'm using Plato so it messed up the code a bit. After changing the kind values to be 8, and setting iteration to initially be 0 I was able to get the solution I wanted. Thank you for your help.